# can't make textview bold on motorola atrix

Tags: android, textview, motorola, bold

did anyone encounter this problem? 
xml attribute android:textStyle="bold" doesn't seem to have an effect on motorola atrix.

couldn't find solution anywhere.. would appreciate some help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that they've customized the default font, and added one that does not have a bold style associated with it. I don't have and have not used an Atrix, so I can't say for sure, but that would be my first guess.

You could try using a different font face as well, i.e. Sans instead of Serif, and see if the other one has a bold style. Worst case, you could download the Droid fonts from Google, and embed them into your application, and override TextView to use those instead of the default system fonts.

Comment: thanks. it only happens in hebrew font, and i think they did override the default font. but i don't know if it bothers me enought to go through the trouble :)